# moving MS config settings to a new profile?

Tags: windows-7, user-profiles, export, import, msconfig

Since my profile for my main user is screwed up I created a new user and then did a copy and paste of the contents from the old user to the new user. How can I export all of these settings (boot, startup, services, etc.) from the old user and then how do I import them to the new user?

The screwed up profile takes 15-17 min. after a successful login before the system is ready to do anything. Before the screwed up profile it would take approximately 5-7 min. to go from login to ready.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the built-in [Easy Transfer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-easy-transfer), which will move your profile settings.

You'll need to start it up on the old login then have it save out to a file to import into the new login.

During the import, you can choose what folders and which registry keys to import in.

But you have to ask yourself, "If I have no idea what went wrong with the old profile in the first place, is it wise to import **any of the old settings?**"

Comment: that is why I am interested in just exporting/importing the stuff from MS config – the new user/profile seems to work very well but I don't want to use msconfig on the new user "manually" if there is an easier way to do things…

Comment: Then Easy Transfer should be the ticket.

Comment: easy transfer seems to be great for transferring everything except the startup stuff in msconfig – I have the entire disk already transferred and the new profile works well. How do I transfer only the startup items from one profile to another? Cut and paste does not work. So how do I do this?